# Как сделать передачу аргумента в getopt возможной, но не обязательной?

Tags: c, getopt

Вот код

```
bool grep_parse(grep_info *info, char *argv[], int argc, pattern *patterns,
count *count_patt) {
    opterr = 0;
    int res;
    while ((res = getopt(argc, argv, "e:i:v:n:l:c:")) != -1) {
        switch (res) {
            case 'e':
            info->flag_e = true;
            patterns->e_patterns[count_patt->e_count] = optarg;
            puts("info->flag_e = true;");
            printf("-e arg = '%s'\n", optarg);
            count_patt->e_count++;
            break; case 'i':
            info->flag_i = true; 
            patterns->i_patterns[count_patt->i_count] = optarg;
            count_patt->i_count++;
            break; case 'l':
            info->flag_l = true;
            patterns->l_patterns[count_patt->l_count] = optarg;
            count_patt->l_count++; 
            break; case 'v':
            info->flag_v = true;
            patterns->v_patterns[count_patt->v_count] = optarg;
            count_patt->v_count++;
            break; case 'c':
            patterns->c_patterns[count_patt->c_count] = optarg;
            puts("info->flag_c = true;");
            printf("-c arg = '%s'\n", optarg);
            count_patt->c_count++;
            info->flag_c = true;
            break; case 'n':
            patterns->n_patterns[count_patt->n_count] = optarg;
            count_patt->n_count++;
            info->flag_n = true;
            break;
            default:
            return false;
        }
    }
    printf("flags processed, optind = %d\n", optind);
    if (optind < argc) {
        puts("free args:");
    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
        puts(argv[i]);
    }
    grep_distribution(info, argv, argc, optind, patterns, count_patt);
    return true;
}

void grep_distribution(grep_info *info, char *argv[], 
int argc, int optind, pattern *patterns, count *count_patt) {
    char *file_name = malloc(sizeof(char));
    bool flag = false;
    if (argc - optind > 1) {
        flag = true;
    }
    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++) {
        file_name = argv[i];
        FILE * file = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (!file) {
            printf("жесть с файлом\n");
        } else {
        if (info->flag_c) {
            grep_c(file, patterns, count_patt->c_count, file_name, flag);
        }
        if (info->flag_n) {
            grep_n(file, patterns->n_patterns, count_patt->n_count, file_name, flag);
        }
        if (info->flag_e) {
            grep_e(file, patterns->e_patterns, count_patt->e_count, file_name, flag);
        }
        if (info->flag_i) {
            grep_i(file, patterns->i_patterns, count_patt->i_count, file_name, flag);
        }
        if (info->flag_l) {
            grep_l(file, patterns->l_patterns, count_patt->l_count, file_name, flag);
        }
        if (info->flag_v) {
            grep_v(file, patterns->v_patterns, count_patt->v_count, file_name, flag);
        }
        }
    }
    //free(file_name);
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что в случае приведенного ниже примера вывода `getopt` принимает флаг `-е` за аргумент. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы он этого не делал? Флаг `-с` может содержать аргументы, но если далее следует другой флаг, то предполагается, что его паттерн распространяется и на предыдущий (как я поняла из работы grep)

Пример вывода:

```
pe@vo-a1 grep % gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra test.c            
pe@vo-a1 grep % ./a.out -c -e int -e include test_1_grep.txt
info->flag_c = true;
-c arg = '-e'
flags processed, optind = 3
free args:
int
-e
include
test_1_grep.txt
жесть с файлом
жесть с файлом
жесть с файлом
test_1_grep.txt:0
```

Comment: Смотрите, что пишут: 
Note that glibc's nonconformant argument permutation extension will break any attempt to use multiple arguments to -i in this manner. And on non-GNU systems, the "second argument to -i" will be interpreted as the first non-option argument, halting any further option parsing. With these issues in mind, I would drop getopt and write your own command line parser if you want to use this syntax, since it's not a syntax supported by getopt - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939157/c-getopt-multiple-value

Comment: Большая просьба, научитесь по человечески форматировать код. Просто нет сил смотреть на кашу из `case` и `break` без всяких отступов и пустых строк (в логически нужных местах кода)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное в [man getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) использование optional аргументов описано как-то невнятно.

Если вы хотите, чтобы у ключа `-c` был необязательный (optional) аргумент, то в строке ключей, передаваемых в `getopt()` после него надо написать два двоеточия -- `::`. Т.е. ваша строка должна иметь вид -- `"e:i:v:n:l:c::"`.

В этом случае аргумент для ключа `-c` при вызове программы надо задавать **без пробела** между ключем и аргументом.

Если вызвать программу вот так

```
./a.out -c123 -e arg
```

то в цикле разбора аргументов

```
while ((res = getopt(argc, argv, "e:i:v:n:l:c::")) != -1) {
   switch (res) {
      .....
```

будет вызван

```
  case 'c':
```

и `optarg` будет равен "123"

При вызове

```
./a.out -c -e arg
```

также будет вызван `case 'c':`, а `optarg` в этом случае будет установлен в NULL.